# How to determine pairings table?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

For example, you have four players, then the parings are:

```
  round1: 1-4, 2,3
   round2: 4-3 , 1-2
   round3: 2-4, 3-1
```

So every player plays once against each other.

But what is the algorithme for it? SO that you can also manage it for 6 players, of 8?

Thank you

I ask this because I play sometimes chess with some others. For example: 4 players, or 6 players. And then I have to make a crosstable, like:

```
        1  2 4 4
Jan  
Adriaan
Piet
Niels
```

for six players you will get this:

```
1   1 - (6) 2 - 5   3 - 4
2   (6) - 4 5 - 3   1 - 2
3   2 - (6) 3 - 1   4 - 5
4   (6) - 5 1 - 4   2 - 3
5   3 - (6) 4 - 2   5 - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the players on two sides of a long table. $$\begin{array}{cccc}1&2&3&4\\\hline8&7&6&5\end{array}$$
Player 1 stays where he is; everyone else rotates one place along.
$$\begin{array}{cccc}1&8&2&3\\\hline7&6&5&4\end{array}$$
For each new round, rotate everyone except player 1 around the table.

Comment: ...then 6  would never play 4?

Comment: When 6 is sitting next to 1.

Comment: But the problem is if 1 always stays on the same place , then it doesnt work, For exmaple with four players: you will get then 1-4, 1-3 and 1-2 . What is ofcourse not correct

Comment: @Michael ...so for $2n$ players the total is just $2n-1$ by this?

Comment: Yes.  2n players, everyone has 2n-1 opponents, so they play everyone in 2n-1 rounds.  There are lots of other ways to do it - as you say, in a single round there are $(2n)!/2^nn!$ possible pairings - but this gets all individual matches played.

Comment: Savant - With four players, round 1: 1-4, 2-3. round 2:1-3,4-2, round 3:1-2,3-4.  Everyone has played everyone else.

Comment: Ah, I'v got. The one doesnt stick on his place every round, it works alternately

Comment: Yes, I agree. I misread the question, will remove my answer.

Comment: Savant - the one does stick on his place every round.

Comment: But then you will get for example with four players: 1-4, 1-3, 1-2. But that is nor correct

Comment: Ok, but a player cant have three times white. He/she can have two times white of two times black. Like in my example

Comment: it has to be like swiss system

Comment: Perhaps $1$ can alternate, and everyone on $1$'s side of the table play the same colour as $1$.